# mysql no connection but why is this happening

Tags: mysql, connection

In localhost/blah/index.php it lets me login, register accs, etc.
I uploaded my website it to my webhost.
I go to my website but i see no mysql connection.

It works fine on my localhost/phpmyadmin/xampp or w/e u call it
What is making this happen?
Finding a new webhost and or updating my php version is not an option

Comment: `Please don't tell me. Well actually tell me.` Should we tell you or not tell you? Decide on that first.

Comment: You have a very *very* strange way of asking a question / asking for help.

Comment: Back to your question. have you ensured that the settings on your server are proper?

Comment: You both have a very strange way of helping a member, and why the -4?
What did i do wrong?!?

Comment: Your question lacked details/context. The wording was inappropriate (to be honest the first time i read the highlighted sentence above I could'nt supress a smile, sorry about that).

Comment: My question was specific, detailed, contextual, appropriate, and 
written well enough where a user can answer my question; as did two members below.
And your statement lacks what I call correct punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you use your local database settings. Update them to the server database settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have MySQL on your server.
Check connection setting for MySQL on the server.
Upload or create database/table as required on the server.